# Cannot run Junit test on ADT, because it always gets terminated

Tags: android, unit-testing, mobile, junit

We are developing "Productivity" application for Android platform, and we are currently trying to test database of the application with Junit tests. The application has classes for tasks, checklist and projects etc. The database is just a java class called DatabaseHandler that is integrated with sql. The current tests are on CRUD operation on the tasks. When junit tests are created, it auto generated empty tests, that should fail and say "Not yet implemented". So we just wanted to test it, however, got a problem straight away. The junit tests just won't run. What happens is, it gets terminated and does not run the test.
Here is the code of this test:

```
package com.example.gobi.test;

import android.test.AndroidTestCase;

public class DatabaseHandlerTest extends AndroidTestCase {

public DatabaseHandlerTest(String name) {
super();
}

protected void setUp() throws Exception {
super.setUp();
}

protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
super.tearDown();
}

public void testGetInstance() {
fail("Not yet implemented");
}

public void testOnCreateSQLiteDatabase() {
fail("Not yet implemented");
}

public void testOnUpgradeSQLiteDatabaseIntInt() {
fail("Not yet implemented");
}

public void testAddTask() {
fail("Not yet implemented");
}

public void testGetTask() {
fail("Not yet implemented");
}

public void testGetAllTasks() {
fail("Not yet implemented");
}

public void testUpdateTask() {
fail("Not yet implemented");
}

public void testDeleteTask() {
fail("Not yet implemented");
}

public void testGetTaskCount() {
fail("Not yet implemented");
}

}
```

Please let me know if you can see what is wrong with code or the set up.
Edit: I found out that I was doing it wrong. Its not run as, it should be debug as android junit test. After that it does not get terminated. 
However now I have got another problem. It says that source file is not found:"The jar file in /..../ has no source attachment."
I google what jar file is. But I can't understand what it is in terms of my project...